# What is the best approach to get first row as key (dictionary) and rest of the row (values) in list python?

Tags: python-3.x

From the test.csv file, I have

```
country,first_name,last_name,address
Australia,test1,test2,address1
Hongkong,test2,test3,address2
```

How can I read the csv file and assign country as key in dictionary and test of the row as values?

Expected output:

```
{"Australia": ["test1","test2","address1"], "Hongkong": ["test2","test3","address2"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension

```
txt= '''country,first_name,last_name,address
Australia,test1,test2,address1
Hongkong,test2,test3,address2'''

{line.split(',')[0] : line.split(',')[1:] for line in txt.split('\n')[1:]}

# {'Australia': ['test1', 'test2', 'address1'], 'Hongkong': ['test2', 'test3', 'address2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an option using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module with a dict-comprehension:

```
from csv import reader

with open('test.csv') as file:
    lines = reader(file)
    next(lines)  # skip the header
    dct = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in lines}

# {'Australia': ['test1', 'test2', 'address1'], 
#  'Hongkong': ['test2', 'test3', 'address2']}
```

assuming that `test.csv` looks like

```
country,first_name,last_name,address
Australia,test1,test2,address1
Hongkong,test2,test3,address2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv` module for creating your dictionary, open the file using `csv.reader`, and build the dictionary as you iterate throw the rows.

```
import csv

dct = {}

#Open csv file
with open('test.csv') as fp:
    #Open reader instance 
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    #Skip header
    next(reader)
    #Iterate through rows and update dictionaries as you go 
    for row in reader:
        dct[row[0]] = row[1:]

print(dct)
```

So if the file looks like

```
country,first_name,last_name,address
Australia,test1,test2,address1
Hongkong,test2,test3,address2
```

The output will be

```
{'Australia': ['test1', 'test2', 'address1'], 
'Hongkong': ['test2', 'test3', 'address2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a rather simple example of how you can do this.  First opening a file and creating an empty dictionary.  Next we can work with each line of your file independently using a for loop.  Then, for each line you `strip` any extra nonsense on the end (such as `\n`) then `split` your line up based on your delimiter (`,`).  Set the first element of this list to the key and the rest t the value of your dictionary.

```
a = open("textfile.txt")
mydict = {}
for i in a: 
    j = i.strip("\n").split(",")
    mydict[j[0]] = j[1:]

print(mydict)
```