# Create dictionary from CSV where column names are keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to read a csv file (actually a tsv, but nvm) and set it as a dictionary where its key are the column names of said csv and the rest of the rows are values for those keys.
I also have some comments marked by the '#' character, which I intend to ignore:

***csv_in.csv***

```
##Some comments
##Can ignore these lines
Location   Form                  Range         <-- This would be the header
North      Dodecahedron          Limited       <---|
East       Toroidal polyhedron   Flexible      <------ These lines would be lists
South      Icosidodecahedron     Limited       <---|
```

The main idea is to store them like this:

```
final_dict = {'Location': ['North','East','South'], 
'Form': ['Dodecahedron','Toroidal polyhedron','Icosidodecahedron'],
'Range': ['Limited','Flexible','Limited']}
```

So far I could come close like so:

***tryercode.py***

```
import csv
dct = {}

# Open csv file
with open(tsvfile) as file_in:
# Open reader instance with tab delimeter
reader = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter='\t')
# Iterate through rows 
for row in reader:
    # First I skip those rows that start with '#'
    if row[0].startswith('#'):
        pass
    elif row[0].startswith('L'):
        # Here I try to keep the first row that starts with the letter 'L' in a separate list
        # and insert this first row values as keys with empty lists inside
        dictkeys_list = []
        for i in range(len(row)):
            dictkeys_list.append(row[i])
            dct[row[i]] = []
    else:
        # Insert each row indexes as values by the quantity of rows
        print('¿?')
```

So far, the dictionary's skeleton looks fine:

```
print(dct)
{'Location': [], 'Form': [], 'Range': []}
```

But everything I tried so far failed to append the values to the keys' empty lists the way it is intended. Only could do so for the first row.

```
        (...)
    else:
        # Insert each row indexes as values by the quantity of rows
        print('¿?')
        for j in range(len(row)):
            dct[dictkeys_list[j]] = row[j]   # Here I indicate the intented key of the dict through the preoviously list of key names
```

I searched far and wide stackoverflow but couldn't find it for this way (the code template is inspired by an answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132656/what-is-the-best-approach-to-get-first-row-as-key-dictionary-and-rest-of-the-r), but the dictionary is of a different structure.

Comment: For that very last line use `dct[dictkeys_list[j]].append(row[j])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amend something in your code and run it. Your code can work with the right result.

The code is below

```
import csv
dct = {}

# Open csv file
tsvfile="./tsv.csv"  # This is the tsv file path
with open(tsvfile) as file_in:
# Open reader instance with tab delimeter
    reader = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
    # First I skip those rows that start with '#'
        if row[0].startswith('#'):
            pass
        elif row[0].startswith('L'):
        # Here I try to keep the first row that starts with the letter 'L' in a separate list
        # and insert this first row values as keys with empty lists inside
            dictkeys_list = []
            for i in range(len(row)):
                dictkeys_list.append(row[i])
                dct[row[i]] = []
        else:
        # Insert each row indexes as values by the quantity of rows
            for i in range(len(row)):
                dct[dictkeys_list[i]].append(row[i])
print(dct)
# Iterate through rows
```

Running result like this
[image]
Besides, I amend your further like below, I think the code can deal with more complicated situation

```
import csv
dct = {}

# Open csv file
tsvfile="./tsv.csv"  # This is the tsv file path
is_head=True    # judge if the first line
with open(tsvfile) as file_in:
# Open reader instance with tab delimeter
    reader = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        # First I skip those rows that start with '#'
        # Use strip() to remove the space char of each item
        if row.__len__()==0 or row[0].strip().startswith('#'):
            pass
        elif is_head:
        # Here I try to keep the first row that starts with the letter 'L' in a separate list
        # and insert this first row values as keys with empty lists inside
            is_head=False
            dictkeys_list = []
            for i in range(len(row)):
                item=row[i].strip()
                dictkeys_list.append(item)
                dct[item] = []
        else:
        # Insert each row indexes as values by the quantity of rows
            for i in range(len(row)):
                dct[dictkeys_list[i]].append(row[i].strip())
print(dct)
# Iterate through rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), we can create a dictionary that automatically initialises its values as lists.  Then we can iterate over a [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to populate the `defaultdict`.

Given this data:

```
A,B,C
a,b,c
aa,bb,cc
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

This code

```py
import collections
import csv

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('myfile.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for k, v in row.items():
            d[k].append(v)
print(d)
```

Produces this result:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
                             'B': ['b', 'bb', 'bbb'], 
                             'C': ['c', 'cc', 'ccc']})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why did I get errors all the time? I got this error `NameError: name 'buf' is not defined`

Comment: @YasserKhalil `buf ` was a typo - it should have been `f`.  I've corrected the example - thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you and sorry for my trivial questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("csv_in.csv")
df.to_dict(orient="list")
```

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce this, I have created a csv file with below content and saved as 'csvfile.csv'.

```
Location,Form,Range
North,Dodecahedron,Limited
East,Toroidal polyhedron,Flexible
South,Icosidodecahedron,Limited
```

Now to achieve your goal, I have used pandas library as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df_csv = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')
dict_csv = df_csv.to_dict(orient='list')
print(dict_csv)
```

and here's the output as you needed:

```
{'Location': ['North', 'East', 'South'],
 'Form': ['Dodecahedron', 'Toroidal polyhedron', 'Icosidodecahedron'],
 'Range': ['Limited', 'Flexible', 'Limited']}
```

Hope, this helps.